# "Can't connect to MySQL server", only when client is remote server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm having a weird problem where I can connect to a certain database server from my local machine (and my friend can also connect to the database server from his local machine) but we can't connect to the database server from his AWS server.

What I get on the AWS server is:

```
"Can't connect to MySQL server on '<IP address>' ".
```

It's not as if the database server is only allowing connections from certain IP addresses; it didn't know about my IP address before I tried to connect.

Any idea what could be different about my AWS machine that could be making the connection not work?

Comment: It sounds like both clients that can connect are on the local network, whereas clients that are not on the local network are unable to connect.  Is that correct?  If so, perhaps this is a NAT traversal or port-forwarding problem?

Comment: If the IP address of your database server is non-routing, like `10.x.x.x` or `192.168.x.x` or approximately `172.16.x.x` then it won't be accessible on the public internet without a VPN, port mapping, or tunnelling. As a note, exposing your database server to the public internet is generally a **bad idea**.

Comment: @tadman Is there a particular resource or google search term you'd recommend for me to learn the proper way to do this? "database connection tunneling", maybe?

Comment: Actually, I think the link that @ZoAnimus provided is probably what I need. I didn't see that a second ago.

Comment: On your router, you need to create a port-forwarding rule to forward incoming connections on port 3306 to the local ip address of your MySQL server.  Then, from the AWS client, connect to the public (outside) ip address of your router (not the local 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x address of your MySQL server on your LAN).  But, be careful with security.  By default, MySQL does not use SSL or any type of encryption, so everything (including your MySQL login credentials) will be in clear text.  And anyone will be able to connect to your MySQL server from any IP, unless you create more firewall rules.

Comment: It's usually best to do this over an SSH tunnel, where everything's encrypted (See: SSH port forwarding), or via a VPN. If that's not an option, be sure to heavily firewall that port and only allow access from specific IPs if that's possible.

Comment: I am not sure but I would like to set up a VPN configuration so that the database on my PC can be reached by a remote shared host server via a PHP script. So my first guess is that the two servers must have a VPN installed, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the MySQL server inside the same network as the local machines?   If so, it might explain why local machines can connect but the remote AWS can not.

By default, MySQL disables all remote connections.  You can check if the remote connections are enabled.  It could also be an issue with port block.  MySQL uses port 3306 by default.  Either MySQL or the AWS might not be configured to send data through the firewall on port 3306.

Here is a decent article explaining how to open these things up.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html